# Unable to archive the app in Xcode for submission

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, iphone-developer-program

I want to archive the app in Xcode, for that I created the provisioning profile manually and downloaded and installed as per the instructions. I did it manually as  with automatic signing it was asking to register a iPhone device which I don't have. When the provisioning certificate is loaded it is still asking me to register a device for archiving.

What should I do? please tell me so that I can archive the app and submit it

Comment: Select generic device in build target while archiving and try

Comment: I did selected the generic device

Comment: Are you trying to archive an ad hoc build or distribution build??